# Example of independence of functions of dependent random variables

Tags: functions, random-variables, independence

Is it true that it is not possible for functions of dependent random variables to be independent?

For example, if $X_1, ..., X_n$ are dependent, then it is impossible for $Y_1 = X_1^2, ..., Y_n = X_n^2$ to be independent ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible. Let $X$ be a random variable with the distribution $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, and let $Y=-X$. Then $X,Y$ are obviously dependent. However, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are both constant random variables, so they are independent.

Comment: A nontrivial example:  let $U,V$ be iid $N(0,1)$ and let $X=U$, and $Y=\mathrm{sign}(X) |V|$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (their signs are forced to be equal) but $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are nontrivial independent rvs.

Comment: Thanks for examples! But it is impossible to have such independence for exactly quadratic function, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly quadratic function"?